# Java Optional.map() error: "Cannot infer type argument(s) for <U> map(Function<? super T,? extends U>)"

Tags: java, option-type

I done lately more Scala and I exercise now a bit Java 8.
Here is the code:

```
    Optional<String> bikeOpt2 = Optional.ofNullable("Pegas");
    out.println(bikeOpt2);
    
    bikeOpt2.map(out::println); // at this point Eclipse underlines in red and says  "Cannot infer type argument(s) for <U> map(Function<? super T,? extends U>)"
```

How should I write it to compile ?

Comment: `Optional.map` takes a `Function`. A function does not return `void` (which is what `println` returns)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` should be used only when there is an `Optional` result.

What you're looking for is

```
bikeOpt2.ifPresent(out::println);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. but it feels so unnatural compared to Scala. In Scala Option.map will compile and if isEmpty then it does nothing.

Comment: @doom: that's what `Optional.map` does too, but it just requires you to have a result you're getting out.